# Find the volume of this solid of revolution using the shell method.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region enclosed by $y=x^3$ and $y={\sqrt{x}}$ about the line $y=1$.

So far my set up is: $$\int_0^1 2\pi (1-y)(y^{1/3} - y^2) dy$$

But this yields $$\frac{10\pi}{21}$$ Am I correct in this answer?

Comment: It looks like you've set it up right...

Comment: ...and I think the evaluation is correct too.

Comment: Yep, that's it.